# Grant only stored procedure rights for a user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to have a database user only have rights to execute stored procedures and functions.  This needs to be a dynamic setting so that every time i add a stored procedure or function they have rights to it.

**Constraints**
I cannot change the names of the schema or stored prcedures or functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 and newer, you can create a new database role

```
CREATE ROLE db_executor
```

and then grant that role the permission to execute - without specifying anything.

```
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor
```

This role can now execute all stored procedures and function in the database - and it will be able to execute any **future** stored procedures you add to the database, too!

So now just add this role to your user and you're done:

```
exec sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db_executor', @membername = 'your-user-name-here'
```

PS: of course, you could also grant this permission to just a single user:

```
GRANT EXECUTE TO your-user-name
```

This makes management a nightmare, however - so I wouldn't go down that path..